# How to pass local variables to global variables in typescript?

Tags: typescript, variables, global

How do i get the value of variable 'price' and pass it as a global variable so I can use it elsewhere in my program?

```
gdax.loadMidMarketPrice(product).then((price: BigJS) => {
    console.log('Mid-market Price: $${price}/BTC');
}).catch(logError);
```

I tried this but the variable is not visible outside the function

```
gdax.loadMidMarketPrice(product).then((price: BigJS) => {
    var midprice=price;
    console.log('Mid-market Price: $${price}/BTC');
}).catch(logError);
```

Comment: In a browser: `window['midprice'] = price;`. In Node.js: `global['midprice'] = price;`. Then you have to `declare var midprice: any` somewhere in a file TS definition file. But it is a **very bad practice**.

Comment: how is this used?  do you want to make this available? in what environment, what other technologies.

Comment: Just want to make the variable available to other functions in the same typescript file.

Comment: that's a bit vague too, how are those functions called? you could just move the `var midprice` outside the **then** function. But the variable will be initialized asynchronously and it might be null if used before the callback finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you say you have everything in the same typescript file. Then simply move the variable out of the function

```
var midprice;

gdax.loadMidMarketPrice(product).then((price: BigJS) => {
    midprice = price;
    console.log('Mid-market Price: $${price}/BTC');
    someOtherFunc();
}).catch(logError);

function someOtherFunc() {
    console.log("Hey, I can see it! It's " + midprice);
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but the console log would say midprice is undefined

Comment: @Jin Then something is wrong with your code. In my example `midprice` is set BEFORE `someOtherFunc` is called and therefor the variable must exist. Maybe you tried some other code and are accessing `midprice` before it is set? Maybe you can get replace the unknown `gdax.loadMidMarketPrice` call in your example with a dummy so we can reproduce your exact problem?